# How to insert into one table by joing other table?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

```
table1
id | mcc | mnc | active | client_id
1    202   05      1        4
2    202   06      0        4 
.......a lot

table2
id | mcc | mnc | rejectReason
1    202   05         null
2    202   06         null
```

Need to insert into table2, but need to check each of table1's item for inserting of table2 something like this:

```
 SELECT table1 t1

(CASE WHEN t2.id != 0
THEN
  INSERT INTO table2 t22
  SET (
       t22.rejectReason = CONCAT('LOSS OF COVERAGE'),
       t22.mcc = t1.mcc,
       t22.mnc = t1.mnc,
  )
 WHERE t22.mcc     = t1.mcc
 AND   t22.mnc     = t1.mnc
 ELSE
   ''
END)

 LEFT JOIN table2 t2
 ON  t2.mcc       = t1.mcc
 AND t2.mnc       = t1.mnc
```

If table1 has not this item(mcc/mnc) like table2 then insert current item for table2. Help please

```
RESULT:
```

```js
 table1
    id | mcc | mnc | active | client_id
    1    202   05      1        4
    2    202   06      0        4 
    3    214    0      1        5
    .....
         212    16     // not exist 
         214    07     // not exist 
    .......a lot
    
    table2
    id | mcc | mnc | rejectReason
    1    202   05         null
    2    202   06         null
    3    212   16         LOSS OF COVERAGE // then insert 
    4    214   07         LOSS OF COVERAGE // then insert
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I didn't quite understand what you want, but here is a structure of how it should be, adjust it to what you meant:

```
UPDATE table2 t2
LEFT JOIN table1 t1
 ON(t1.mcc = t2.mcc and t1.mnc = t2.mnc)
SET t2.rejectReason = 'LOSS OF COVERAGE'
WHERE t1.id is null
```

This will update `t2.rejectReason` to 'LOSS OF COVERAGE' when there is no record with the same `mcc,mnc` on table 1. By the way, `CONCAT()` is used to unite more then 1 string, you also have one so you don't need it.

**EDIT:** if you want an insert then:

```
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT t.id,t.mcc,t.mnc,'LOSS OF COVERAGE'
FROM Table1 t
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 from table2 s
                 WHERE t.mcc = s.mcc and t.mnc = s.mnc)
```

**EDIT2:** I don't know this error, so maybe it can be solved more easily , but you can do this:

```
CREATE TABLE Temp_Tbl AS
(SELECT t.id,t.mcc,t.mnc,'LOSS OF COVERAGE'
FROM Table1 t
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 from table2 s
                 WHERE t.mcc = s.mcc and t.mnc = s.mnc));

INSERT INTO Table2
SELECT * FROM Temp_Tbl;

DROP TABLE Temp_Tbl;
```

Comment: What exactly do you want  to happen? Provide an expected output please.

Comment: i added result, what i need i think

Comment: I get error: MySQL docs say: "You cannot refer to a TEMPORARY table more than once in the same query." | Earler : CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE newData ENGINE = MEMORY AS(...)

Comment: @axon I think it fixed, now:)